# Can't see Loaded, Initialized, Visible window

Tags: c#, wpf

**Simplified version**

1. `ParentWindow.ShowDialog()`
2. Click default/Bring Up Child Window button in ParentWindow
3. Click event handler for default/Bring Up Child Window button does `ParentWindow.Hide()`
4. `ChildWindow.ShowDialog()`
5. Click ChildWindow's cancel/Go Back button
6. `ParentWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`
7. ParentWindow is nowhere to be found.

I checked, and ParentWindow returns true for `IsInitialized`, `IsLoaded`, and `IsVisible`. I also Alt-Tabbed my way through all my windows to look for it - it's not hiding under anything.

Why can't I see ParentWindow anywhere?

---

**Full version**

1. `parseSettingsWindow.ShowDialog()`
2. Click default/Bring Up Fix Selector button in parseSettingsWindow
3. Click event handler for default/Bring Up Fix Selector button does:
    a. `ParentWindow.Hide()`
    b. parseSettingsWindow.GoToNextWindow flag set to true (Next window is Fix Selector)
4. `while` loop does `fixSelector.ShowDialog()` because it's not yet loaded
5. Click ChildWindow's cancel/Go Back button
6. `while` loop is entered again, goes to `case "Parse Settings" section
7. `parseSettingsWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`
8. parseSettingsWindow is nowhere to be found

I checked, and parseSettingsWindow returns true for `IsInitialized`, `IsLoaded`, and `IsVisible` in the Immediate Window when pausing execution on the `break;` line of the "Parse Settings" `while` loop section. I also Alt-Tabbed my way through all my windows to look for it - it's not hiding under anything.

Why can't I see parseSettingsWindow anywhere?

---

**Main class**

```
    public static bool UserPromptedSettingsWereWrittenToModel(ref Model model, ref ActiveFixes activeFixes, ref ActiveReports activeReports)
    {
        var viewModel = new ViewModel();

        var parseSettingsWindow = new ViewPlusViewModel.ParseSettings();
        parseSettingsWindow.InitializeComponent();

        var fixSelector = new ViewPlusViewModel.FixSelector(viewModel);
        fixSelector.InitializeComponent();

        var seeAllFixesReports = new ViewPlusViewModel.SeeAllFixesReports();
        seeAllFixesReports.InitializeComponent();


        parseSettingsWindow.ShowDialog();
        var nextWindowToOpen = "Fix Selector";


        while (parseSettingsWindow.GoToNextWindow == true && fixSelector.GoToNextWindow == false)
        {
            switch(nextWindowToOpen)
            {
                case "Fix Selector":
                    if (fixSelector.IsLoaded)
                    {
                        fixSelector.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fixSelector.ShowDialog();
                    }

                    nextWindowToOpen = "Parse Settings";
                    break;
                case "Parse Settings":
                    parseSettingsWindow.GoToNextWindow = false;
                    parseSettingsWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    nextWindowToOpen = "Fix Selector";
                    break;
            }
        }


        if (parseSettingsWindow.GoToNextWindow == false)
        {
            parseSettingsWindow.Close();
            if (fixSelector.IsLoaded) fixSelector.Close();
            if (seeAllFixesReports.IsLoaded) { seeAllFixesReports.Close(); }
            return false;
        }

        parseSettingsWindow.Close();
        fixSelector.Close();
        if (seeAllFixesReports.IsLoaded) { seeAllFixesReports.Close(); }

        return true;
    }
```

---

**ParseSettingsWindow.cs**

```
    private void GoToNextWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.GoToNextWindow = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't bring a hidden `.ShowDialog()` window back again via `Window.Visibility`. You need to use `.ShowDialog()` on it again. In addition, any buttons given the `IsCancel = True` property will no longer have that functionality even when using `ShowDialog()` again, so presses on that button will need to be handled manually.